# Git Permission Denied

Tags: git, sudo

So I seem to have been a bit carless with sudo when trying to setup my git account was following a tutorial and this is what I entered

```
458  git credential-osxkeychain
459  curl -s -O http://github-media-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/osx/git-credential-osxkeychain
460  git credential-osxkeychain
461  which git
462  sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain /usr/bin/git
463  git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
464  sudo git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
```

now wheneverI try any type of git command I receive the message

```
-bash: /usr/bin/git: Permission denied
```

Any help would be very very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
chmod a+x /usr/bin/git
```

or:

```
chmod 755 /usr/bin/git
```